# How activerecord delete all if not exist in other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Condition:
There are two tables: source_table and target_table which need to sync sometime later.
In part of the process, it needs to delete all target_table records that do not exist in source_table
I want to use ActiveRecord
But what I can do is to iterate which is not look as good as some SQL like below in ActiveRecord

```
DELETE a FROM a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE b.foreign_key_of_A_in_B = a.id_A);
```

SourceTable(id:integer, tracking_id: integer, date_created: date)
There are 10 records
TargetTable(id:integer, tracking_id: integer, date_created: date)
There are 15 records with 5 records different than sources

Want to operate to have TargetTable only eg: 10 records (if date range covered all)
But that not always the case because date range may selected
Since it a lot's of records (millions)

Comment: What exactly is your question? How to solve this in SQL? Or With ActiveRecord executing SQL? Or in pure ActiveRecord? Or just how to do this in a performant way?

Comment: Solve in ActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

Rails 6.1 introduced `missing`

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
end

class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author
end
```

```
Author.where.missing(:books).delete_all
```

or

```
Author.includes(:books).where(books: { author_id: nil }).delete_all
```

Comment: The two databases are separated, It is created to sync when needed in a certain period (there are date field) but both have a key eg: transaction_id to control

Comment: I will try "Author.includes(:books).where(books: { author_id: nil }).delete_all"